# How can I horizontally align checkmarks in a table column?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, dcolumn, pifont

In my table I use different combinations of a checkmark standing alone, in parentheses, or with an asterisk. I would like to have a centered column in which the checkmarks align.

By using the package `dcolumn` and defining the checkmark as decimal point I get the desired alignment. However, when running this through pdfLaTeX I encounter two problems:

1. `\ding{51}` is not printed correctly even though I loaded the package `pifont`.
2. The column is not center aligned anymore.

Why does this happen and how can I get the desired result?

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{A}{D{.}{\ding{51}}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
 \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Availability}\\
 \midrule
 Some Element & \ding{51}\\ 
 Another Element & \ding{51}\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered}\\
 Yet Another Element & (\ding{51})\\
 One More Element & (\ding{51}\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered})\\
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Unaligned example table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XA}
 \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Availability}\\
 \midrule
 Some Element & .\\
 Another Element & .\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered}\\
 Yet Another Element & (.)\\
 One More Element & (.\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered})\\
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Aligned example table, but with problems displaying the checkmark and messed up centering.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that columns of type `D` from the `dcolumn` package always use math mode, and `\ding{51}` in math mode is printed as `3`.

So, you can force its contents to be in text mode, substituting the line

```
\newcolumntype{A}{D{.}{\ding{51}}{-1}}
```

with

```
\newcolumntype{A}{D{.}{\textrm{\ding{51}}}{-1}}
```

Note that, for the same reason, you can substitute `\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered}` with `^*`

To keep the first line centered use `\multicolumn`, otherwise it will check for the alignment point.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{A}{D{.}{\textrm{\ding{51}}}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
 \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Availability}\\
 \midrule
 Some Element & \ding{51}\\
 Another Element & \ding{51}\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered}\\
 Yet Another Element & (\ding{51})\\
 One More Element & (\ding{51}\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered})\\
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Unaligned example table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XA}
 \textbf{Element} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Availability}}\\
 \midrule
 Some Element & .\\
 Another Element & .^*\\
 Yet Another Element & (.)\\
 One More Element & (.^*)\\
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Aligned example table, but with problems displaying the checkmark and messed up centering.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]